# Using an array to store multiple variables from user input

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, user-input

I am relatively new to Java and would like to know how to store variables separately from a single line of user input.

At the minute the user is prompted to enter football results in the following format

```
home_name : away_name : home_score : away_score
```

and I am using a while loop to continue to ask user for input until they enter "stop"

```
(while (input != "stop))
```

Once the loop is broken I would like my program to output a variety of data such as total games played, but I'm struggling to store the `home_name`, `away_name` etc.. especially if the user wishes to enter multiple lines of results.

Comment: (Assuming the user wishes to enter 100 lines of match results)

Comment: Please post whatever code you have, and point to a specific problem that you are having.  It will, well, help **us** help **you**.

Comment: tagged with Java, as the questions is about java.......

Comment: `boolean stop = true;                                                                                           while (stop)
  {
  System.out.println("Please enter results in the following format"
    + " home_name : away_name : home_score : away_score"
    + ", or enter stop to quit");
  
  String response = scan.nextLine();
  if (response.equals("stop"))
  {
   stop = false;
  } 
 
  }`

Comment: That's about it at the minute, I would like to know how to split each line of input into separate parts to store separately

Answer (score 0):

Two mainstream ways to store a "record" are:

- Maps
- Data objects

A map is more generic:

```
Map<String,String> match = new HashMap<>();
match.put("home_name", "Alvechurch Villa");
match.put("away_name", "Leamington");
match.put("home_score", "0");
match.put("away_score", "6");
```

You can add a map to a list:

```
List<Map<String,String>> matches = new ArrayList<>();
matches.add(list);
```

... and retrieve them:

```
Map<String,String> match = matches.get(0);
System.out.println(match.get("away_score"));
```

---

A data object is more tuned to your data format, but you have to write the class yourself.

```
public class Match {
    public String homeName;
    public String awayName;
    public int homeScore;
    public int awayScore;
}
```

Now you can use this class:

```
 Match match = new Match();
 match.homeName = "Studley";
 // etc.
```

You can add and retrieve these from lists too:

```
 List<Match> matches = new ArrayList<>();
 matches.add(match);
 Match aMatch = matches.get(0);
```

This is simple, but it's considered bad practice to have public fields like this - it's better to get at them via methods. For brevity, here's a data class with only one field:

```
 public class Player {
     private String name;
     public Player(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }

     public String name() {
         return name;
     }
 }

 Player neilStacey = new Player("Neil Stacey");
```

You can use the same technique with all the fields in `Match`.

(A common style is to name a method like this `getName()`, and also to have a `setName()`. I have used a different style and made the object *immutable*, in an effort to set a good example!)

---

One advantage of the data object is that it has different types for different fields: `homeName` is a String, `homeScore` is an integer. All the fields in the Map are Strings. You can get around this by using `Map<String,Object>` but then as a consumer you have to cast to the right type when you read.

```
 String homeName = (String) match.get("home_name");
```

Data objects allow the compiler to do a lot of compile-time checking that helps you know your code is correct. If you use a map, you won't find out until runtime.

Comment: I understand briefly, but I am still struggling to get my head around how I would take each variable and store it from the user input when the following format is entered = home_name : away_name : home_score : away_score. I do not want to prompt the user separately for each input.

Comment: For example, my current base structure looks like this...                      boolean stop = true;
  
  while (stop)
  {
  System.out.println("Please enter results in the following format"
    + " home_team_name : away_team_name : home_team_score : away_team_score"
    + ", or enter stop to quit");
  
  String response = scan.nextLine();
  if (response.equals("stop"))
  {
   stop = false;
  } 
  }

Comment: It looks like you asked a question about storing variables, when actually you want to know how to split a string. Google "Java split string".

Answer (score 0):

Prompt the user separately for each input.

```
System.out.println("home_name: ");
String hN = scan.next();
System.out.println("away_name: ");
String aN = scan.next();
System.out.println("home_score: ");
String hS = scan.next();
System.out.println("away_score: ");
String aS = scan.next();
```

Comment: I would like the users to input in the following format only =home_name : away_name : home_score : away_score, not separately for each variable.